# Why python With each loop advances, the processing time increases?

Tags: python

I have written a program in which I am reading the SINEX file. I select multiple SINEX files in one go and start my loop. In each loop, the program will read the file and extract the data. The problem is that, for 1st loop, it takes 2 minutes, then in the second loop, it takes 5 min, third loop, it takes 10 min, in the fourth loop, it takes more than 20 min and so on. Why with every loop, the amount of time it takes increases, and how can I fix it. Hereby I am giving my code. Any help or suggestion will be really appreciable.

```
for file_name in filename:      # Selecting file from the file list
# Finding the counter at which certain pattern comes. The index will be one less than counter
breakPoint = search_string_in_file(file_name, '*---------------')
# Reading the data between the pattern
for i in range(3,len(breakPoint)-1):
    df, fname = reading_data_bw_lines(file_name, breakPoint[i]+2, breakPoint[i+1]-2)
    df.to_csv(fname)
```

Comment: please, fix the indentation of your snippet

Comment: How are you measuring the time between files? I would include some measure of a line count and/ or time stamp at each loop iteration, and it will show you exactly what the issue is.